# Does Intel Chipset Q75 support Asus GT 545?

Tags: graphics-card

I have tried to find GPU for Intel Chipset Q75. 
GTX 960 failed. Now, testing Asus GT 545 which seems to fail. 
Power supply requirement is ok with the 300 W.

Does Intel Chipset Q75 support Asus GT 545?

Comment: What do you mean failed. the Intel Chipset Q75 supports PCIe 2.x which both the GTX 960 and the GT 545 will work on.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question.  The question you should be asking is the reason the `GTX 960` didn't work.  Will a 5 generation old GPU work with your hardware? It absolutely will.

Answer (score 0):

As per **Intel ARK** (http://ark.intel.com/products/64033/Intel-BD82Q75-PCH), Q75 chipset supports:

- PCI Support:     Yes
- **PCI Express Revision:  2.0**
- PCI Express Configurations ‡:    x1, x2, x4
- Max # of PCI Express Lanes:  8

So it should support both GTX960 and GT545. However, you would need to post whole configuration to troubleshoot whether it's not your PSU or other part of configuration failing here. Either way, it's definetely not incompatibility of motherboard.